# Prove that Orthogonal Set Is Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V$ is an inner-product space; $(\space ,\space )$ is our inner-product.
I have seen many proofs that go as follows:

Let $\{x_1, x_2 ,\ldots, x_n\}$ be orthogonal.  Set $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = 0$.

Then, for each $k$, $a_k(x_k, x_k) = \left(\sum_i a_ix_i, x_k\right) = (0, x_k) = 0$.

Since $x_k$ is nonzero, we must have $a_k = 0$ for all $k$.

My question pertains to the equality $(0, x_k) = 0$.  If I understand the definition correctly, this equality holds in the case where the inner-product is the dot-product, but does not hold in general.

So, I did this instead:  $0 = (0, 0) = \left(\sum_i a_ix_i, \sum_i a_ix_i\right) = \sum_i {a_i}^2(x_i, x_i)$.

Since $x_i \neq 0$, $(x_i, x_i) > 0$, entailing that $a_i = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: For **any** inner product, you will have $\langle 0, x \rangle = 0$. The missing part above is that $\langle \sum_i a_i x_i , x_k \rangle = a_k \langle x_k, x_k \rangle= a_k \|x_k\|^2$ if the $x_j$ are orthogonal.

Comment: I think I got it. $(0, x) = (0x, x) = 0$. I spoke too soon ....

Comment: Depending on your definition, the inner product is linear (or conjugate linear) in one argument with the other fixed. Hence if either argument is zero the inner product will be zero.

Answer (score 2):

First, for **any** inner product $\;\langle,\rangle\;$ in any vector space $\;V\;$ with inner product, we certainly have that

$$\forall\,x\in V\;,\;\;\;\langle 0,x\rangle=\langle 0\cdot 0,x\rangle=0\cdot\langle 0,x\rangle=0$$

Observe that after the first equality above, one $\;0\;$ is a vector whereas the other one is a scalar.

Second, and for the linearly independent thing:

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i=0\implies\,\forall\,k=1,2,...,n\;:\;\;$$

$$0=\langle0,x_k\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i,x_k\right\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\langle x_i,x_k\rangle=a_k$$

and thus $\;a_k=0\;\;$ **for all** $\; k=1,2,...,n\;$ , and we get what we wanted.